# Where data goes to store if we uses Hadoop to handle bigdata because hadoop database HBase stores Structured data whereas big data is unstructured

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Hadoop is used for handling big data and hadoop uses HBase as its database, but BigData likely 80% is unstructured and HBase only stores Structured data.

Where Unstructured data goes to store ? Or are there any tools of hadoop converts the unstructured data into structured format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Big data" does not imply any existence of a structure, but most datasets are semi structured, otherwise it would be difficult to parse consistently.

HBase sits on top of HDFS. And Hbase can store binary blobs, therefore its data can be used to store unstructured data.

HDFS can store any type of data. It has no metadata about the contents of the files

You generally use Hive (MetaStore) for applying a structure of your HDFS datasets